# Pass scope to element.after()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The below is called in my HTML:

```
<input data-autocomplete>
```

There is a parsing error (basic HTML error) because when `data-autocomplete` is ran, it calls another directive inside its HTML: `data-autocomplete-results`. When this is run/compiled, it creates a div inside of the `<input>` element and because that is bad HTML it means it doesn't show up despite it being in the source.

A solution is the below example of my compile inside of a directive inside of an `<inupt>` element.

```
compile: function(element) {
    element.after('<div data-autocomplete-results></div>');
}
```

However, unlicke `element.append`, `element.after` does not pass the scope and is essentially, I think, a static piece of html. The directive is called in the appended div but of course the stuff inside that, that rely on the scope, do not work.

Is there a way to pass the scope to this `element.after`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating an angular element and compiling it against the scope you want it to have with $compile

e.g.

```
var newElement = angular.element('<div data-autocomplete-results></div>');
element.after($compile(newElement)(scope));
```

Also you would need to do this in the link function, as scope is unavailable during the compile phase of the digest cycle.

Comment: Thanks, that's spot on. Unfortunately its used twice on the page so they are both being updated. I'm not to sured up on scopes, I don't suppose you would have a good resource for learning such things?